# Add missing CRS to sf object in R simple features

Tags: r, mapping, gis, r-sf

Is there a way to add missing CRS? I have been given some old Esri shapefiles and a large proportion of them have `CRS: NA`, I'd like to be able to batch set the missing CRS. I can set it manually when I import into QGIS but can't seem to set it using R. I tried `st_transform()` but it doesn't seem to work if there is no CRS set in the first place.

Comment: `st_transform()` transforms the CRS, i.e., it changes it from one projection to another. You're looking for `st_crs() <-` or `st_set_crs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I tried `st_crs <-` and `st_set_crs()` but still couldn't seem to get it set correctly or plot the shapefiles. I noticed the ones with missing `.prj` files were the ones that had no CRS which makes sense. so I wrote a chunk to create a proj file for each shapefile in the directory if one does not allready exist. Bit of a hack but it works :)

EDIT: Added a crude logging system to track the changes

```
p = "/path/to/shape/files"

proj_str_bng = 'PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999601272],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'

proj_str_wgs84 = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'

shp_to_prj <- list.files(paste0(wd, p), pattern = "\\.shp$")

if (!file.exists(paste0(wd,p,"prj_log"))){
write("file, dt", file = paste0(wd,p,"prj_log"))
}

for (i in 1:length(shp_to_prj)) {
  shp_to_prj[[i]] <- paste0(wd, p, str_remove_all(shp_to_prj[[i]], ".shp"), ".prj")
  if(file.exists(shp_to_prj[[i]])) {
    next
  }
  write(proj_str_bng, file = shp_to_prj[[i]])
  write(paste0( shp_to_prj[[i]], ",",Sys.time()), file = paste0(wd,p,"prj_log"), append=TRUE)
}
write(paste0( "^===============================================================^", ",",Sys.time()), file = paste0(wd,p,"prj_log"), append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned trying to use st_set_crs() but you need to make sure that you are using a very specific syntax (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590209/how-to-set-crs-for-a-shp-polygon-file-in-r))  I was trying to use st_set_crs() using a normal syntax eg.

`st_set_crs(myObj,crs)`

and it didn't work until using the "piped syntax"

`myObj = myObj %>% st_set_crs(myEPSGNumber)`.

I think you can also set the crs when you read the shapefile initially:

`myObj = st_read("myObj.shp",crs=st_crs(myEPSGNumber)`

It took me a while to figure it out, but hopefully will either help you or some other wayward soul!